# Visual Studio 2012 - MS Excel 2013 Templates only, backward compatibility?

Tags: visual-studio, compatibility

I'll be starting a new project in Visual Studio 2012, using a VB Excel template but the only options are for Excel 2013 (there are three options around Add-in, Template or Workbook) but majority of the users will be using 2007 and 2010 Excel.

Would an Excel 2013 project be backward compatible with 2007 and 2010? Or must I download a separate template that is not offered in the vanilla version of VS2012?

Thanks :)

These are the project options:

[image: These are the project options:]

Comment: got the same problem but it's been a year since last activity on this topic. Have you by any chance found a solution? I have tried [**THIS**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40790) and [**THAT**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=12365) but none of them seem to be installing the template for 2010 :/

Comment: Nah sorry, I gave up on this alternative and moved to a completely different platform cause it was turning out to be more troublesome than the project was worth! Good luck to you though!

Comment: [**here we go**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803024/visual-studio-2012-ms-excel-2013-templates-only-backward-compatibility/22766290#22766290) @Chronix3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, [image]

Select `.NET Framework 4` and you will be able to see all the templates...

Comment: Thanks for following up! Good for future reference :)