# C# WPF: Adding custom Usercontrol to Stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, stackpanel

I tried a few things about adding my own created user control element to listbox or stackpanel, but instead of gaining any success, it causes a **NullReferenceException** and I have no idea why ...

my user control is looking like that:

```
public partial class ShiftInformationItem : UserControl
{
    public ShiftInformationItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and the xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <LabelContent="Benutzername:" />
    <Label Content="01.03.2014 14:19" />
    <TextBox Text="Eintrag ..." />
    <Expander Header="Comments (0)">
        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Inside the main window I can add it in a listbox or a stackpanel without any Trouble:

```
<ListBox>
     <controls:ShiftInformationItem  />
</ListBox>
```

or:

```
<StackPanel Name="ShiftInformationPanel">
     <controls:ShiftInformationItem  />
</StackPanel>
```

But when I try to add it with C#:

```
ShiftInformationList.Items.Add(new ShiftInformationItem());
ShiftInformationPanel.Children.Add(new ShiftInformationItem());
```

it causes the **NullReferenceException** and says the object I want to add is null.

Does anybody can explain me why?

Im very thankful for all well meaned and helpful answers in advance!

UPDATE:

```
public partial class HoBusReceptionMain : Window
{
    public HoBusReceptionMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void RibbonWin_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RibbonTab r = (RibbonTab)e.AddedItems[0];
        switch (r.Header.ToString())
        {
            case "Shift Information":
                InitializeShiftInformationTab();
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show(e.AddedItems[0].ToString());
                break;
        }
    }

    private void InitializeShiftInformationTab()
    {
        //here I want to add the new ShiftInformationItem
    }

}
```

UPDATE 2:

Thanks all comments, it Shows up, that my list || Panel is null ... But both is included in the main window (above HoBusReceptionMain)

I use Ribbons in my application, and when a ribbon tab is selected or loaded the **RibbonWin_SelectionChanged** Event is fired ... The list or Panel defined below the ribbon definitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are adding that before `InitializeComponent()` gets called.

**Move the code of adding below InitializeComponent()** and it will work like it did from XAML. Issue is controls were not initialized before `InitializeComponent()` gets called and hence resulting in `NullReferenceException`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ShiftInformationList.Items.Add(new ShiftInformationItem());
    ShiftInformationPanel.Children.Add(new ShiftInformationItem());
    // ShiftInformationPanel is null here
}
```

Comment: The Addings are in another code script, the Initializing of ShiftInformationItem should be called on "new ShiftInformationItem()"

Comment: `ShiftInformationPanel` is null and not `ShiftInformationItem`. Make sure code script is run after UI gets initialized.

Comment: Sorry, you understand it wrong, maybe I haven't clearly explained.

    ShiftInformationList.Items.Add(new ShiftInformationItem());
    ShiftInformationPanel.Children.Add(new ShiftInformationItem());

is called in my main window, where I want to add the **ShiftInformationItem**

Comment: neither my list nor my Panel can't be null, it's after initializing

Comment: I misspelled correctly in my answer. I meant that addition code should run after `MainWindow's InitializeComponent` only.

Comment: Can you see with debugger attached that what value is evaluating out to be null?

Comment: dammit guys, you are right, my list || Panel is indeed null ... The ChangeEvent is obvious fired, before it's initialized ... But how is that possible? and more important: how do I avoid that?

Comment: Where is `ShiftInformationList` declared? Where is this `SelectionChanged` is hooked?

Comment: It's both declared in my main window (HoBusReceptionMain)

Comment: Please add details in question. Otherwise it all will be guess work without it. I meant that how it's declared and how event is hooked for it because in ideal case it won't be null.

Comment: @TobiasRaphaelDieckmann sorry to be off-topic here but you seemed to be looking for a solution to [**THIS PROBLEM**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803024/visual-studio-2012-ms-excel-2013-templates-only-backward-compatibility/), once you see it please mark this comment for removal