# How to run a method in a VSTO Word Template from a separate .NET application?

Tags: .net, vba, templates, ms-word, vsto

I'm working on a project that involves migrating macros in a **Word Template** to VB.NET making use of VSTO. We've been able to create the Word Template and migrate the code to VB.NET just fine, however we need to action a certain VSTO method from a separate .NET application.

Previously, we were able to achieve this in VBA by doing this:

```
Word.Application.Run(MacroName:="MyDocument.MyModule.MyMethod")
```

There are a few articles explaining how this can be achieved with Application and Document-level customizations, but we've yet to find any information on how this can be done with a **VSTO Document-level Word Template**.

We've already tried a number of different approaches including:

- Exposing the class and method as outlined in this [How to expose a C# class to a VBA module in a document-level add-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22787956)
- Introducing a VBA macro (which we can access from the .NET application), that can action the VSTO method as [outlined in this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386306(v=vs.100).aspx)

However neither of these seems to be applicable for document-level templates. In addition to this we also tried adding a button to the ribbon which fires the required method, and attempting to access it from our .NET application using `Word.Application.CommandBars.FindControl()`

Some more info: the VSTO Word Template was created using VS2013, and the separate .NET application has been developed on VS2010. Both applications run .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard .Net mechanisms such as WCF (.Net Remoting) and etc. Consider your document level add-in as a separate application.

In case of application level add-ins, you can call them directly. See [Calling Code in Application-Level Add-ins from Other Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608621.aspx) for more information.

Comment: We've looked at the application-level customization, however it doesn't apply to our project as we're working with document-level customization. We have some knowledge of WCF as we use it to communicate with some Windows hosted services. Could you elaborate on how WCF could be used to call a VSTO method from another .NET application?

Comment: Yes, the link I mentioned can't be applied to document-level customizations. Use .Net remoting for communication between your applications. You may consider your document-level add-in as a regular .net application.