# Creating a custom Excel add-in

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm trying to create a custom Excel add-in.I currently have Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and Microsoft Excel 2010.The problem that I currently have is that when I create a new Excel Add-in project and I try to build, it says that **I haven't got a proper version of Office installed** and it provides a link for reference. Whenever I visit the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242.aspx) it actually says that Excel 2010 **is** supported. Whenever I start excel it actually loads the add-in in the list of installed add-ins,but I cannot debug or run it in Visual Studio!  Has anyone had any problems with  this?

Comment: Funny, I have VS2010 and Office2013 and I cannot build an add-in also. Maybe we should trade?!

Comment: D-E-F-I-N-I-T-E-L-Y !! :D

Comment: Seriously, I think MS has screwed the pooch with VSTO. It has made it so much harder for non professionals to develop automation in Excel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 - MS Excel 2013 Templates only, backward compatibility?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803024/visual-studio-2012-ms-excel-2013-templates-only-backward-compatibility)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the actual question...